# Android ProGuard: Getting an error of 'Use of generics not allowed for java type at '<1>_<2>_<3>JsonAdapter' in line 43 of file ...'

Tags: android, jenkins-pipeline, proguard, moshi

I implemented a library on my gradle that uses Moshi as a dependency. When I tried to compile locally and also creating an android build through jenkins, it shows an error of

```
Use of generics not allowed for java type at '<1>_<2>_<3>JsonAdapter' in line 43 of file '\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-moshi-1.9.3.jar\76f6a6d7d5642e8be11f9d49dc24d752\META-INF\proguard\moshi.pro'
```

I already indicated rules on my proguard.pro file as stated on the documentation of the library I used but still errors are still encountering. I also tried the solution on the issues tab of moshi on github but I still received an error build.

Here's my proguard-rules.pro file

```
#ChatvisorLibrary
-keep class com.chatvisor.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.chatvisor.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**

#Dependencies
#Protocol Buffers
-keep class com.google.**
-dontwarn com.google.**

#Moshi (https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/moshi/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/moshi.pro)

# JSR 305 annotations are for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.* <methods>;
}

-keep @com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier interface *

# Enum field names are used by the integrated EnumJsonAdapter.
# values() is synthesized by the Kotlin compiler and is used by EnumJsonAdapter indirectly
# Annotate enums with @JsonClass(generateAdapter = false) to use them with Moshi.
-keepclassmembers @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    <fields>;
    **[] values();
}

-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
public private protected *;
}
```

I hope someone could help me and get resolved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already resolved this issue by upgrading my Proguard version

https://www.guardsquare.com/en/blog/proguard-61-released